# Copying an existing database to device memory from the assets folder

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to copy a database file from the assets folder to the device /data/data folder for reference by the app. This copy process keeps failing.

I have used a copyDatabase() method found in the answers to similar problems on stackoverflow. These methods use an InputStream variable set by context().getAssets().open(databaseName); however, in my case, this assignment fails to populate a database. A subsequent method that queries the db throws an exception, since the database has no table 'main' as expected.

This is my copyDatabase() method:

```
 String DATABASE_NAME = "birdsDBase3.db"

       private void copyDatabase(String DATABASE_PATH){
            Log.i(TAG, "now in copyDatabase()");
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "trying to copy database.");
                InputStream assetDB = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
                Log.i(TAG, assetDB.toString());
                OutputStream appDataBase = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_PATH, false);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = assetDB.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    appDataBase.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                appDataBase.flush();
                appDataBase.close();
                assetDB.close();
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Error from log: "SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: category"

I want the database to copy over to the device so that another method can send a query for distinct tuples in one column. Instead, this method fails due to the absence of a 'main' table in the database. I know that the query is well formed because I have run it within the SQLite Browser and got the expected result, and the method has been checked in a different thread on stackoverflow.

Comment: What is the file name ? And whats the Exception you are getting ? Edit the question with  details

Comment: @ADM Thanks, I have added the file name and exception above.

Comment: NO such table means the DB isn't copied . There should be an exception in copyDatabase method ... Follow[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/ship-an-application-with-a-database) ..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the issue is simple that the database hasn't been correctly saved (not a rare occurrence so check and double check that the file copied into the assets folder is populated accordingly) then the likely issue is as per :-

Since the advent of Android 9 many of the older methods of copying the database from the assets folder now fail. This due to using the **getWritableDatabase** method to create the databases folder into which the database is copied.

That is when an App is installed the folders **data/data/package** are created for the App's data. SQlite databases are be default stored in **/data/data/package/databases**, the copy will fail with a **NOENT** if the databases folder doesn't exist.

Using the SQLiteOpenHelper's **getWritableDatabase** will create the **databases** folder when it creates the database, whihc is typically the same name/file as the database to be copied from the assets folder and the final database name.

Before Android 9 the default logging used was journal mode. This mode uses a file named the same as the database name but suffixed with -journal. The file contains transactions and can be used to roll back the transaction from the actual database.

With Android 9 Write-Ahead Logging (WAL) is used be default. This writes the actual transaction to a file **-wal**, (which is effectively part of the database and looked at first) and when a checkpoint occurs the database file is updated and the -wal file cleared.

The -wal file is therefore instrinsic, if it exists it MUST belong to the database for which it was created.

So what happens is that getWritableDatabase creates a database, and some transactions, such as creating the android_metadata table are written to the -wal file. The database is copied from the assets file overwriting the newly created database but the -wal and the -shm files (a shared memory file used by WAL) remain. When the database is opened the error results in an unusable database, due to the -wal and -shm files not belonging to the copied database, and the SDK/API creates a usable new database and hence no tables that existed in the asset file that was copied.

The solutions can be :-

1. Disable WAL by calling the SQLiteDatabase's [disableWriteAheadLogging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#disableWriteAheadLogging) method before the database has been used.

   - If using a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper, generally by overriding the **onConfigure** method of the SQLiteOpenHelper.
   - Not recommended as the benefits of WAL are lost.
2. Using a different database name to create the databases folder (never known that to be done).

   - Awkward, never tried and thus not considered.
3. Deleting or renaming the -wal and -shm files before the copied database is opened.

   - The best option so far but...
4. Create the databases folder using standard/basic File handling i.e. by using `the_databases_parent_file.mkdirs();`

   - The **best and recommended option** as
   - it does not have the overheads of opening the database file
   - doing the checks
   - creating the android_metadata table
   - creating and writing the -wal and -shm files
   - overwriting the intermediate database file
   - deleting the -wal and -shm files
   - affords the advantages of WAL

An example that uses this technique when checking for the existence of the database file is :-

```
private boolean checkDataBase(Context context, String databaseName) {
    /**
     * Does not open the database instead checks to see if the file exists
     * also creates the databases directory if it does not exists
     * (the real reason why the database is opened, which appears to result in issues)
     */

    File db = new File(context.getDatabasePath(databaseName).getPath()); //Get the file name of the database
    Log.d("DBPATH","DB Path is " + db.getPath()); //TODO remove for Live App
    if (db.exists()) return true; // If it exists then return doing nothing

    // Get the parent (directory in which the database file would be)
    File dbdir = db.getParentFile();
    // If the directory does not exits then make the directory (and higher level directories)
    if (!dbdir.exists()) {
        db.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        dbdir.mkdirs();
    }
    return false;
}
```

To implemnt the above your would use the above to check the database and do away with the **getWritableDatabase** that is called between checking the database and calling the **copyDatbase** method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement

> SqliteAssetHelper

Search over the web and try it.